# TouchableOpacity onPress event doesn't work on Absolute parent, and Relative the parent's parent

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-native, position

This is my code :

```
            <View style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
                {
                    open &&
                    <View style={styles.selectorContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemContainer} onPress={() => { console.log('hi') }}>
                            <Typography>{'aaa'}</Typography>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                }
            </View>
```

This is the styling :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    },
    selectorContainer: {
        backgroundColor: color.white,
        ...dropShadow,
        position: 'absolute',
    },
    itemContainer: {
        paddingVertical: 8,
        paddingHorizontal: 16,
        backgroundColor: color.white,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    }
})
```

I tried to make a Dropdown list and this is how far i've got.

i set the ItemsContainer parent to have a `position: relative` so that the itemsContainer position can be set to "absolute" and so the itemContainer is relative to it parent.

this is going the way i want,

but...

when i add `<TouchableOpacity />` component inside ItemsContainer the onPress function did not get fired

please help

Comment: Did you tried zIndex in selectorContainer?

Comment: yes, but it still didnt work

Comment: i am not sure if you're tappable area is too small. i added some padding to the selectContianer and can see the console.log's https://imgur.com/a/PTVTH4r

Comment: hi!, update here...
it turns out that because my screen component or others... im not really sure where, has zIndex. so i got to add zIndex to the container (which has position relative)
i hope this help anyone with same issue, cheers!